# Lwc getPicklistValues not working on OpportunityLineItem

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, wire

I am trying to get picklist values for the field on OpportunityLineItem, but getting `{}`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import SUB_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem.SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c';

export default class LwcGetpicklistDemo extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: undefined, fieldApiName: SUB_TYPE })
    propertyOrFunction;

    get stringPkl() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.propertyOrFunction);
    }
}
```

As OpportunityLineItem doesn't support record types, the default recordTypeId for it is always null. I tried to pass `null, undefined, ''` values to `recordTypeId` attribute of `getPicklistValues` method. But no luck

Comment: I believe if you use the 'master record type' - `012000000000000AAA` for objects like this, it does return the picklist values.

Comment: @AntonioManente it does not, I got this `{"error":{"ok":false,"status":404,"statusText":"NOT_FOUND","body":[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]}}
`

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that error is caused by this. I spun up a quick PoC and it does indeed return the picklist values without error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, it is not supported by the object which doesn't support record types. Till then I have used auraMethod to get those values.

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<SelectOption> getOppItemPickListValues(String fieldApiName){
    List<SelectOption> pickListValuesList= new List<SelectOption>();
    if(string.isNotBlank(fieldApiName)){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap= OpportunityLineItem.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldsMap.get(fieldApiName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
            pickListValuesList.add(new SelectOption(pickListVal.getValue(),pickListVal.getLabel()));
        }
    }
    return pickListValuesList;
}
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import SUB_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem.SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c';
import getOppItemPickListValues from '@salesforce/apex/DirectSalesCompController.getOppItemPickListValues';

export default class LwcGetpicklistDemo extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getOppItemPickListValues, {
        fieldApiName: SUB_TYPE.fieldApiName
    })
    typePicklistValues;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template if:true={typePicklistValues.data}>
    <lightning-combobox label="Subscription Type" value={dropPipeJSLProduct.SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c}
        placeholder="-Select-" options={typePicklistValues.data}
        onchange={handleSubscriptionType}></lightning-combobox>
</template>
```